# BC42105: Function '<procedurename>' doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: vb.net, function

I tried all possible solutions and they didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Function '' doesn't return a value on all code paths is my error

```
Public Function Isprime(n2 As Long)
    Dim n, i As Integer
    Dim b As Boolean
    Console.WriteLine("enter a no : \")
    n = Console.ReadLine()
    i = 2
    b = True
    While i < n
        If n Mod i = 0 Then
            b = False
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End While
    If b Then
        Console.WriteLine("prime no")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("not prime no\")
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()

End Function


Public Function PrimePairs(ByVal n As Long, ByVal n2 As Long) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Console.ReadLine()
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
        For i = 1 To (n / 2) + 1
            n2 = n - i
            If Isprime(i) And Isprime(n2) = True Then
                count += 1
            End If
        Next

    Else
        n2 = n - 2
        If Isprime(n2) = True Then
            count = +1
        End If

    End If

    Console.WriteLine(count)
    Return n
End Function
```

End Module

Comment: The IsPrime() function does not return a value at all.  It is missing `Return Not b`.  Declaring the function `As Boolean` won't hurt.

Comment: or declare it as `Sub` if you do not intend to return a value. It is not usual to return a value and at the same time to call `WrinteLine`. Either write a `Sub` calling `WriteLine` OR use a `Function` returning a value. If this was done for debugging, then read [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) for a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You function does not return a value and is quite convoluted. It does I/O and does a prime test at the same time. Separate logic from I/O.

```vb
Public Function IsPrime(n As Long) As Boolean
    n = Math.Abs(n) ' Allows to consider negative prime numbers
    If n < 2 Then   ' Disallows -1, 0, 1
        Return False
    End If

    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    While i < n ' Note that for n = 2 we don't enter the loop and thus return True.
        If n Mod i = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
    Return True
End Function
```

Also, it is missing a return type. Always work with [`Option Explicit On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) for better code quality.

Note that you can return when you hit the first prime factor. There is no point in continuing the loop then.

---

But there are ways to optimize this. For example we could test the divisibility by 2 separately and then test only odd divisors and it is enough to test divisors up to the square root of `n`.

```vb
Public Function IsPrime(n As Long) As Boolean
    n = Math.Abs(n)
    If n = 2 Then
        Return True
    End If
    If n < 2 Or n Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Return False
    End If

    Dim i As Long = 3
    Dim limit As Long = CLng(Math.Sqrt(n))
    While i <= limit
        If n Mod i = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
        i += 2
    End While
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But now I have another error. my project has not sub "main "so ıt said "No accessible 'Main' method " . How can I fix them ? becuse ı dont have sub main